# breaking data into multiple TCP segments

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, network-programming

When I use a send or write system call to send data on a socket to the destination node, is the kernel/tcp compelled to use the entire buffer in the same TCP segment? Can it break into multiple TCP segments?

Secondly, does IP multiplex multiple TCP segments on a single IP data packet?

Comment: The question does not make really sense to me. What would "break into multiple TCPs" mean? What does "is one to one mapping between the tcp sequence number and IP" mean? I cannot see a relation between IPs and TCP sequence numbers.

Comment: @usr he just means "multiple TCP/IP packets".

Comment: @Alnitak It seems more probable that he meant *TCP segments,* given his last sentence, but it is anybody's guess really. The OP should have used standard terminology, rather than just inventing his own.

Comment: @EJP I suspect that English isn't the OP's first language...

Comment: @Alnitak Irrelevant. I don't accept that it makes any difference. An EE from any country or with any primary language wouldn't talk about voltage where he means inductance. I do not see any reason why terminological rigour shouldn't be expected and required in our domain: especially when we deal with pernickety things like compilers all day long.

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a *stream orientated* protocol.  There is no guarantee (indeed quite the opposite) that a single `write` or `send` will result in a single IP packet.  Similarly a `read` may end up receiving data collected from multiple IP packets.

Multiple TCP streams do *not* ever get merged into single IP packets.

Comment: So there is one to one mapping between the tcp sequence number and IP?

Comment: each TCP packet header will contain the sequence number relating to that packet's position in the stream.  If the TCP packet needs retransmitting, it would have the same sequence number.

Comment: One quick question.. Can I know how much data has been received by the kernel for a particular socket? Usually we specify the number of bytes we want to read from the socket which could be more or less than the bytes received till now

Comment: I don't know any way to find out how much data is there.  You _might_ be able to find out by using `recv` with the `MSG_PEEK` flag.